# Determining the range of a function when given its behavior of the function

Tags: calculus, limits

Say there is a function $h(x)$ where it is continuous on R and $$\lim_{x \to ∞} h(x) = ∞ = \lim_{x \to -∞} h(x)$$

It is also known that from $x>1$ $f'(x) > 0$ and from $x<1$ $f'(x) < 0$

I believe that since the function will approach $∞$ as $x$ reaches $\pm∞$, the fact that $f'(x) < 0$ when $x<1$ indicates that the range of the function should be $(1,∞)$. Am I on the right path? My professor hinted at the use of the Intermediate Value Thereom but I'm not sure how I would apply that here.

Comment: There is no indication what the value of the function is at any point, but you can express the range in terms of $f(1)$. The intermediate value theorem is needed to show that every value $ > f(1) $ is indeed attained and there are no "gaps" on the way to infinity.

Comment: How would we show this though? Since the function was stated to be continuous on R then isn't that guaranteed(that there are no gaps on the way to infinity)?

Comment: Exactly. This seems intuitively obvious but it's a consequence of the IVT: Let $y > f(1)$. To show that $y \in f(\mathbb{R})$ you need to say that there exists $x_1$ with $f(x_1)>y$ by divergence, let's choose such an $x_1 > 1$ and now apply the IVT to conclude that there exists $x_0 \in (1,x_1)$ with $f(x_0) = y$.

Comment: Okay thanks! Shouldn't you post that as an answer though? It did answer my my question

Comment: Probably should have. There's a small bit missing. You need to include an argument (or quote a theorem) for the minimum point to be $(1,f(1))$.